# Cross fade effect without AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I have a video player. In this project I compose videos and images into a single video and map each object in a single video timeline. I want a cross fade effect transition between image-video or video-video but the thing is I don't want to use `AVAssetExportSession` because composed videos are about 2-3 hours can cause many gigabytes which users may not have in their devices.

I was looking for some samples like in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCustomEdit/Introduction/Intro.html) but that uses also `AVAssetExportSession` . Any idea how I can solve cross fade effect issue in real time without exporting the composed video?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `AVMutableComposition`, `AVMutableVideoComposition` and `AVMutableAudioMix` as it should be discussed in the documentation for exporting.

From these objects you can create an `AVPlayerItem`:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:composition];
[playerItem setVideoComposition:videoComposition];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];
```

**EDIT**
Please refer to this sample code here: [AVCompositionDebugViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCompositionDebugViewer)

Comment: how this is helping about cross-fade effect?

Comment: Is your problem the cross-fading itself? It sounds as you would have only trouble getting it into a player...

Comment: Okay, you'll probably want to make that more clear in your question. Give me a few moments, I'm verifying some thoughts in written code and will update my answer

Comment: I have problem with cross fade effect in realtime. Also, I don't want to use AVAssetExportSession.

Comment: Right, as you sad. And everything you _would_ need for an export session can also be used to create an AVPlayerItem, which is used to display / preview.

Comment: if anyone is interested, I ported AVCompositionDebugViewer to Swift 4.2: https://github.com/TizianoCoroneo/AVCompositionDebugView